# Считать из файла текст с несколькими абзацами

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как считать из файла текст, в котором находится несколько абзацев. Я считываю вот так:

```
string text;
ifstream in("input.txt");
if (in.is_open()) 
  getline(in, text);
```

Но данный код считывает только первый абзац. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ваш вопрос можно понять и "как читать файл до конца", и "как считать весь файл в одну строку". Что вы выбираете?... Если хотите точный ответ - задавайте точный вопрос...

Answer (score 2):

Вам показалось что ваша программа прочитала абзац текста. В действительности программа прочитала только одну строку. Просто строка длинная и при отображении не помещается в экран по ширине. Вот вы её и видите как несколько строк или абзац текста. Но технически это одна строка.

Вам нужно прочитать все строки из файла. Проще всего это делать в цикле `while`. `getline` возвращает истину если очередная строка прочитана и ложь иначе:

```
std::string line;
while (getline(in, line)) {
    // process one line
}
```

Если вы не хотите обрабатывать текст построчно, то можно прочитать файл целиком. Прямолинейного способа нет, есть разные трюки. Например трюк, когда вы копируете файловый поток в строковый поток, а из строкового потока получаете строку:

```
stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();
string text = buffer.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

у `string` есть конструктор который принимает `input итераторы`, его можно использовать чтобы записать весь txt файл в строку

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream in("input.txt", std::ios_base::in);
  std::string text(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

  std::cout << text;
}
```

`getline` по умолчанию до `'\n'` (конца строки) считывает или если файл заканчивается, поэтому у вас не весь текст в строке оказывается